# What tolerance class does E3D uses for their metric thread nozzles?

Tags: nozzle, e3d-v6

As we know E3D nozzles use M6 threads. These are metric threads, so they've different tolerance classes but which tolerance class are they using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For making V6 or Mk8 nozzle what tolerance specification we've to follow?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/for-making-v6-or-mk8-nozzle-what-tolerance-specification-weve-to-follow)

Comment: The tolerance of the threads are not really of interest, it is the top of the nozzle and the bottom of the heat break that needs proper care, these are screwed together forming the seal; when properly machined and installed/tightened, no filament will leak to the threads.